# Using vi to edit a file in terminal

Tags: vi

I have a question, I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 and on this machine is icinga software. when I opened the terminal and typed:

```
sudo vi /etc/icinga/objects/localhost.cfg
```

then the terminal opened the file, but I can't type in this file. When I type "d" then the terminal delete everything in the file.

Comment: If you're not familiar with vi, please take a look here [How to edit a file in vi editor](http://askubuntu.com/questions/220065/how-to-edit-a-file-in-vi-editor-arrow-keys-prints-letters), or install vim instead.

Comment: @P.-H.Lin `vim` and `vi` are used the same way. Do you mean to suggest using `nano` instead?

Comment: @EliahKagan nah, the default package is vim.tiny, not vim, you have to do some tweak to make it work like vim.

Comment: @P.-H.Lin The advice in [ps_cool's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/220067/22949) to [How to edit a file in vi editor (arrow keys prints letters)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/220065/how-to-edit-a-file-in-vi-editor-arrow-keys-prints-letters) applies equally to both. Both Ubuntu's default `vi` (as `vim.tiny`) and fuller `vim` installations operate based on the same modal editing concept and have the same basic usage. At the level of answering the question of why typing D deletes a line instead of writing D at the current cursor position, the same answers apply to `vi` and `vim`.

Comment: You may find [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/353940/225694) informative. You might also find [this](https://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/vi.html) useful.

Answer (score 12):

vi = too hard to use for a new user
nano = text editor that is run from the terminal like vi, only it's much easier to use for 2 reasons:

1. The instructions for using nano editor are always found at the bottom of every page.
2. The only two nano keyboard shortcuts that you need to know are for WriteOut and Exit. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file being edited. Press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.

nano is installed by default in Ubuntu.
Tip - Make the terminal easier to read. In the terminal select *Edit* -> *Profile Preferences* -> *Colors* tab and change the *Background color* to black and the *Text color* to white.

Answer (score 10):

`vi` or `vim` is an advanced editor. So I will suggest you to get familiar with it before using it.

For now:

- If you want to edit a file using terminal, press `i` to go into `insert` mode.
- Edit your file and press <kbd>ESC</kbd> and then `:w` to save changes and `:q` to quit.

However, you can combine these two like `:wq` to write and quit the `vim` editor.

---

If you want to learn how to use `vim` editor, use `vimtutor` command, which starts  the  Vim  tutor.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `gksu gedit /etc/icinga/objects/localhost.cfg` to open it in gedit and work from there, if you are having trouble using `vi`.

But G_P is right, type `man vi` in the terminal and it should give you all the instructions.