# OpenSSL and includePath problem

Tags: paths, openssl

I have been encountering this problem for a few weeks now, ever since I started working on my projects. There is a red line under all of my #include lines.

Red lines under #include:

[image: Red lines under #include]

I narrowed the problem down to includePath.

[image: C/C++ Configurations in Visual Studios]

I have searchked online for a long time, but I am still unable to find a proper answer.

https://fedingo.com/how-to-install-openssl-in-ubuntu/

I am currently following the above instructions, but I am stuck at Step 6.

[image: After following till Step 6 from the website and entering $ sudo vi /etc/ld.so.conf.d/openssl-1.1.1c.conf in Ubuntu]

After (E)dit anyway, I am met with this screen below. When I carry on with the website instruction of adding `/usr/local/ssl/lib`, I am getting another error.

[image: After hitting (E)dit anyway and typing in /usr/local/ssl/lib]

I am also not sure how to close Ubuntu by command when this screen appears as "exit" isn't working.

I installed Ubuntu through the Windows Store as that was the way suggested by my university.

Please let me know how I can get rid of the red lines. I am happy to answer any further questions you might have. This is my first time asking a question at Ask Ubuntu.

Edit 1: So far, my C programs work, even with the incorrect path and openssl problem.

Comment: It seems you don't know how to use `vi` to edit files. See https://askubuntu.com/a/524745/158442 or use `nano` instead of `vi`.

Comment: Yes your query is confusing - in fact it seems like a bunch of hardly related queries. What exactly is the "openssl problem" that you are trying to solve? Why are you trying to isntall openssl from source, instead of using the packaged version from Ubuntu's repository? If your programs are compiling, then the "red lines" are likely just an issue with your IDE's syntax highlighting configuration.